# О детях и капусте

Tags: идиоматика

О ткм, что детей находят в капусте, знает каждый взрослый.
Вопрос в том, как они, взрослые, эту капусту представляют.
Или (для тех, кому такая постаноска вопроса покажется недостаточно лингвистической) почему именно там?

ЗЫ Альтернативная школа передовой лингво-биологической мысли, считающая, что все дело в аистах, может не беспокоиться. Рисунок летящей птицы, со свертком в клюве, сомнений не вызывает.

Comment: нужели нет других идей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я где-то читала о том, что иногда капусту и огурцы выращивали вместе. Пока кочан еще не завязался, в него вкладывали огурчик, и там он и рос. А потом, зимой, листы капусты раскрывали - и вот вам, находили свежий огурчик. Автор высказывал мнение, что именно от этого повелась поговорка про детей.

Соверщенно не помню, где это читала. И вообще все похоже на авторскую выдумку. Но занятно!

Comment: Я тоже читал - и тоже не могу поручиться за истинность. Но это не главное. Главное, что вариант тот же. *В кочне*. Лет тридцать назад, когда я сей тест впервы проводил, варианты ответа были совершенно другими.

Comment: А какими? На грядках находили?

Comment: Да! Старшее поколение просто смелаось над тем, что мы не понимаем этого смысла. Шла баба в огород - там среди кочнов и рожала.   
  
А лично я до определенного момента полагал, что речь идет о большой кадушке кислой капусты в погребе. Там у нас еще и не то найдёшь.  
  
Ну и, наконец, версия, что "капуста" - это большой овощной магазин, где детей продают. Или вообще нечто абстрактное, как у Фазиля Искандера в "Удавах и Кроликах" (замечательнейшая, кстати, вещь...).

Comment: Интересно! А дома что, нельзя? Какое-то табу? Все-таки потеплее и помягче будет. Нам, лежащим в больницах, да еще на сохранении, этого не понять...

Comment: Да нет, это сейчас дома сидят, а тогда некогда было. Родит под кустом - и снова в поле, работать.

Answer (score 6):

Может, потому что листьев у капусты много? И чего там между листьями только не попадается...

Answer (score 0):

Тут появилась пятая (или шестая) версия... Не очень, пока её прочувствовал, но добавлю в коллекцию.
[Почему детей находят в капусте?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21731)

Первые были, напомню,
~1. В кочане.
~2. На капустном поле (сравните "[над пропастью]во ржи").
~3. В капусте квашенной.
~4. В овощном магазине/погребе (среди кочанов или отдельно на полках магазина "Капуста").
~5. В абстрактной капусте.
Ну и нынешняя:
~6. В пеленках, напоминающих капусту. Видимо, yupaz тоже об этом, я полгода назад этой мысли совсем не понял.
Надо сказать, что мне эта мысль не слишком в тему, больно уж неестественно менять причину и следствие. Но пусть будет.