# Почему детей находят в капусте?

Tags: фразеология

О том, что "детей находят в капусте", все слышали. Это общеизвестный ответ для самых маленьких на вопрос "откуда берутся дети?" Но почему именно в капусте и откуда вообще пошло именно такое объяснение?

Comment: Я несколько раз пытался этот вопрос поднять в разных сетевых источниках.
И тут тоже:
[О детях и капусте](http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/13784/)

Я пока своего ответа не даю, просто хотелось бы чуть дополнить (уточнить?) вопрос. 
О какой капусте вообще идет речь. Есть как минимум четыре варианта. 
Ответ Надюшки не дают однозначного понимания, о какой-такой капусте речь. 
Ну на уровне картинке. Что не ней будет изображено? 

Для сравнения. С аистом все понятно. Он несет "кулек" в клюве. А с капустой?

Comment: Предполагаю, что:

1) высказывание "Детей находят в капусте." равносильно высказыванию "Детей находят в огороде." (у крестьян огород находился за избой, за мазанкой и т. п.),
2) высказывание "Детей приносят аисты." равносильно высказыванию "Детей находят на крыше." (у некоторых крестьян крыши домов были покрыты соломой.).

P.S.

По моим сведениям, [французского математика] Д'Аламбера нашли на крыльце.

Comment: Возможно, Чукче-писателю, будет интересно узнать следующее:

1) белокочанная капуста - типичный компонент русских щей,

2) в прошлом русские крестьяне очень часто употребляли щи, о чём свидетельствуют пословицы типа "Где щи, там и нас ищи.", "Щи да каша - пища наша.", "Это тебе не лаптем щи хлебать.".

P.S. Мне очень нравятся щи с крапивой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну короче, получается, что тут два вопроса. 
О том, какой смысл вкладывают сейчас - и об истории выражения.
По поводу последнего готов дать вполне однозначный ответ. 
Речь идет о капустном поле. во всяком случае лет тридцать пять - сорок назад подавляющее большинство старшего поколения отвечало именно так - и даже проявляло недоумение в отношении моей непонятливости. Там на грядках "дитё" и появилось.

По поводу же современного смысла - ну тут можно только статистикой и рассуждением, ибо очевидно, что понимание неоднозначно.

История с кочаном не нравится по той причине, что капуста - это кушанье, а про кочан так бы и сказали, это сейчас начали крепко путаться с понятиями. да и размеры не те.

Я же до определенного времени считал, что речь идет о квашеной капусте в бочке.

Идею с "одежкой" похожей якобы на капустные листы так до конца и не понял. Ну да, в чем-то похожи пеленки на капусту, а искать-то где и как? Ко всему прочему, найти в одежде может означать две разные вещи. Найти, одетым или найти в свалке одежды.
Скажем, найти *обутым в сапоги и* в сапоге* как в месте куда кидают рождественские подарки.  
Ребенок (лет до шести - как минимум) такой абстракции не примет. Он понимает то и так, что и как может нарисовать.

Как минимум три варианта подобных картинок легко находятся поиском.

[тут](http://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=_7_7UfPkPMWk4ASrg4GADQ&ved=0CCgQsAQ&biw=1257&bih=907)

Надеюсь, не надо объяснять, в чем принципиальная разница между ребенком в кочане, ребенком среди кочанов и ребенком среди капустных листьев.

Это я к тому, что и современные взрослые тут весьма далеки от однозначности понимания.

Comment: >>капуста - это кушанье

 Капу́ста (лат. Brássica) — род растений семейства Капустные (Brassicaceae) (ранее Крестоцветные (Cruciferae)), к которому относятся такие известные растения, как капуста огородная, горчица, репа и брюква.

 Из Вики. То есть это не кушанье, а вполне себе ботанический термин изначально.

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что это связано с тем, что раньше простые женщины рожали самостоятельно там, где придется:  в поле, (возможно) в огороде или лесу.  И возвращались в дом уже с ребенком на руках. Детям же объясняли появление просто: нашли. Капуста - самый большой овощ :)

Comment: А чуть подробнее?

Comment: Я о капусте белокочанной :) пузатой:)

У Даля нашла в "капусте" вот что: "Сажая капусту, приговаривают: не будь голенаста, будь пузаста; не будь пустая, будь густая; не будь красна, будь вкусна; не будь стара, будь молода; не будь мала, а будь велика." За уши притягиваю, но как вариант - "пузатая" капуста схожа с беременной женщиной, пустая - с бездетной

Comment: Т.е. вы за версию, что в капусте - это в кочне?

Comment: Женщина рожала, а малым детям говорила, что нашла в капусте (белокочанной, в кочане или под листьями). Кочан похож и на беременную женщину.

Comment: Ну скажите русским языком, без рассуждений про беременных, *в кочне* находят или, скажем, рядом?

Comment: Думаю, что это не так важно внутри или около капусты.

Здесь еще статья про капусту http://www.symbolarium.ru/index.php/Капуста

Comment: Если не важно, то это третий вариант. Капуста как абстрактный символ.
Но это не для детей, уверяю Вас. Ответ-то они могут и "принять", но потом все равно домыслят. и вот тут открывается простор для вариантов. От кадушки с кислой капустой, до овощного магазина.

Answer (score 3):

В Италии, например, детей находят "под капустой" и дают  такое объяснение сему факту:
"На протяжении веков в странах Центральной Европы капуста была единственным продуктом, который был в состоянии обеспечить достаточное количество витаминов и минералов в зимнее время года, за что и почиталась как символ жизни и плодородия. Капусту высеивали в марте и собирали спустя 9 месяцев, т.е. ровно столько, сколько длится беременность, в ноябре. Частенько рождение детей совпадало со сбором урожая осенью, поскольку зачатие в большинстве случаев приходилось на весенние месяцы. Причина была проста: свадьбы игрались в основном зимой, когда не надо было работать на полях, а о рождении ребенка можно было начать думать не раньше весны, поскольку только тогда крестьянин мог быть уверен, если годовой урожай сможет гарантировать доход, достаточный для содержания семьи. Сбором капусты занимались исключительно женщины. Сборщиц урожая называли levatrici ("повитухи"), поскольку они перерезали "пуповину", связывающую капусту с землей." Из ресурсов ит. версии Интернета.

А во Франции девочек находят под розами, а мальчиков все под той же капустой :-))

Comment: Девочек под розами :) Красиво!

Answer (score 2):

Склонна думать, что выражение связано со славянскими поверьями. Овощ этот ритуальный. Это своеобразная драгоценность - одна из основных овощных культур образ капусты связан с высшей божественностью - многослоен и многомерен, жизнедарующий и жизнесодержащий, слово "капуста" произошло от древнеримского "капутум" (голова), что подчеркивает своеобразную форму этого овоща. В  период рубки капусты начинались девичьи вечеринки: капустники, капустки, капустинские вечера, которые длились две-три недели. Капустницы – девушки и женщины, пришедшие на рубку капусты, входя в дом, поздравляли хозяев с капустником, как с праздником.  Капуста стоит в ряду растений, наделяемых брачной символикой: за измену парень ссекает капусту на грядках у девушки, которая изменила. Кочан капусты ставили после свадьбы на стол перед родителями нечестной невесты (Минская обл.). Капусту использовали в медицине, зная её целебные свойства, она дарит жизнь. Древнее  поверье говорит,что детей находят в капусте, под листом капусты; их приносит зайчик и сажает на капустной грядке. На Руси ребёнок, рождённый вне брака,- капустничек. Видимо, это всё взаимосвязано.

Есть версия, что впервые шутка о том,что детей в капусте находят, прозвучала во  Франции, а потом распространилась во многие страны.
Кто-то считает, что это пришло из древности, чем-то напоминает греческий миф о том, как Афина Паллада, богиня мудрости, родилась из головы Зевса

http://cabbage.tj/

http://artbull.ru/content/lotos-kapusta-i-pochemu-nashli-v-kapuste

http://pagan.ru/slowar/k/kapusta8.php

Answer (score 2):

Для начала действительно определимся где нашли ребёнка. Взрослые современники К. И. Чуковского даже подумать не могли, что под этим подразумевается что-то кроме капустной грядки, правда у городских детей сложности уже были. Цитата (выделено мной):

> Тебя    нашли    в    капусте !  -  говорят   городскому   ребенку ,  **думая ,  что   он тотчас   же   представит   себе   традиционную   капустную   грядку** .
>      - Разве  я был в супе? - слегка удивляется  он  и тем обнаруживает, что в
> качестве  горожанина никогда не видел огорода.  Капуста  являлась  ему  только в
> тарелке.

Что несколько противоречит французской версии происхождения мема, где маленьких детей называют choupette (дословно: сердцевина капусты).

Теперь, почему в капусте? В капусту, ходили испражняться. Это и для капусты полезно (в начальный период роста она очень требовательна к азоту), и человеку удобно, так как его не видно и подтереться есть чем. В общем, тужилась на капустной грядке, тужилась, а потом - Бац!- и выскочил ребёнок - нашла в капусте. Т.е. понятным для детей языком объясняли процесс родов. Сейчас "городской ребёнок" Чуковского подрос и изначальное понимание забылось окончательно.

Comment: Ну положим, из одного упоминания о традиционной грядке ничего еще не следует. Это означает всего лишь Чуковский думает, что оно традиционно. 
Хотя идея с грядкой, безусловно верна. Откуда, кстати, цитата? В "От двух до пяти я такого не помню", некогда искать...  А, нашел. Странно, что мне раньше никто на неё не указвыал...

Вот что касается испражнений - это хоть стой, хоть падай. Во-первых, не китайцы чай. А коли даже и ходили, то какая связь с "дитем"?

Comment: @behemothus, какой процесс известный ребёнку, больше всего напоминает роды? Испражнение при запоре. Да и резкое уменьшение живота объяснить нужно.

А по поводу "китайцев", у В. И. Даля (Русские заветные пословицы и поговорки) зафиксирована пословица, которая в цензурном виде звучит так: "В степных губерниях что съешь, тем и сходишь, а у нас, чем сходишь (унавозишь), то и съешь". И подобных поговорок зафиксировано немало. Косвенным подтверждением моей версии является, то что упоминаний о детях в капусте в литературе 19-го века нет, но мем явно старше 20-го века.

Comment: Первое упоминание в литературе (Нацкорпус) :
> Л. А. Кассиль. Кондуит и Швамбрания (1928-1931) Что же касается капустного духа, то это нас нисколько не компрометировало: **многие мамаши уверяли**, что всех детей, даже и не приемышей, находят в капусте… 

Лев Кассиль родился в 1905 году.

Comment: Как было дело в 19 веке :
>  -- А правда, что детей приносят ангелы?

>  -- Оно... того... так надо сказать, что детей приносят бабы... таки не кто другой... А душу ангелы приносят. Вот уж это так ваша правда. Вот что, хлопчики: душу... Ну, а мне, хлопчики мои, надо сундук нести, вот что. А то я бы тут вам все это отлично рассказал... (В.Г.Короленко. Очерк "Ночью" (1888)

Вот так вот детям раньше объясняли - "бабы и ангелы". Потом вдруг (на рубеже столетий) появились аисты и капуста! С чем это связано, можно легко понять...

Answer (score 1):

Я всегда представляла грядку. Почему-то с цветной капустой. Может быть потому, что почти не видела, как она растет. А на белокочанную летом деревне насмотрелась вдоволь. Ребнок там лежет между вилками, внутри вилка - это как-то не по размеру. 
Не помню, что туда целенаправленно ходили по нужде. Бегали просто в огород - на ближние грядки. А капусту сажали подальше - так убирать удобнее, это самый поздний овощ.

Answer (score 1):

По моему скромному мнению происхождение следующее: отнимаем 9 месяцев от сроков уборки капусты - Октябрь - 9 = январь - время Коляд - праздник, отдых, свадьбы, праздничная обильная еда. Всё это и давало всплёск рождаемости через 9 месяцев.
Опять - таки: "аист принёс" - апрель - 9 = июль - Купала - славянский праздник с сильной эротической составляющей. Слышал, даже детки, рождённые как плод этого праздника, не считались "безотцовщиной" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Коль ответ всплыл, дам до кучи одно любопытное "исследование (если это так можно назвать)
Скажу сразу, что большая часть аргументации отдельных версий, как и всего подхода в целом, представляется мне за уши притянутой. Но ведь мы же не ставим себе целью реально обосновать метод "капустного зачатия". Мы лишь о том, как этот образ можно понимать. Ну вот автор понимает так и эдак. Аж в шести вариантах. Ну нехай будет.)))

====

ПОЧЕМУ ДЕТЕЙ ИЩУТ В КАПУСТЕ??!

Это меня ребёнок недавно спросил, не нашлась, что ответить.
Теперь - ответ сам нашёлся, и даже не один ответ, а целых пять! И все они связаны с русскими традициями.

☘ПЕРВЫЙ ВАРИАНТ, праздничный.
Высаживали капусту в день Ирины-рассадницы (18 мая).
Рубили - с Крестовоздвижения (27 сентября) до Сергея-капустника (8 октября).
С 9 октября девушки нарядно одевались и шли в одну из изб шинковать капусту для заквашивания. Парни крутились рядом, таскали мешки с капустой и бочки, и при этом шутили и всячески веселили девушек. Отсюда, кстати, пошла традиция весёлых вечеринок с шутками и весельем, которые стали называть капустниками.
После окончания работы хозяева избы устраивали для всех угощение, праздничный ужин заканчивался песнями и плясками. А изредка - и не только ими...
Детишек, которые рождались после такой спонтанной связи, называли "капустничками", и говорили, что их нашли в капусте...

☘ВТОРОЙ ВАРИАНТ - более целомудренный.
На тех же капустниках завязывались пары, которые потом играли свадьбы, и в новых семьях потом рождались дети, которых тоже могли называть капустничками, в память о дне знакомства родителей.

☘ТРЕТИЙ ВАРИАНТ, с капустным полем.
После Рождественского поста игралось много свадеб, после этого зачинались детки, и время родиться им приходило как раз к началу октября...
Огород был женской заботой, а капуста, к тому же, считалась символом женского начала, поэтому убирали её только женщины и, случалось, роды происходили прямо на капустном поле... При этом для чистоты подстилались листья капусты...

☘ЧЕТВРТЫЙ ВАРИАНТ - банный.
Те же листья капусты стелили под роженицу в бане. И чисто, и спалить (по обычаю полагалось сжечь простыни, на которые попадала кровь при родах) - не жалко.
Кроме того, капустный лист - прекрасный целитель, сами убедитесь. Если болят суставы или голова - привяжите лист капусты, станет намного легче. Вот и в родах капуста помогала вытягивать напряжение, расслабиться, чтобы легче родить здоровенького малыша.
И положить малыша после рождения могли тоже капустные листья.

☘ПЯТЫЙ ВАРИАНТ - мистический.
Считалось, что малыш ещё не вполне утвердился в этом мире, и какая-то злая сила может ему повредить, отнять у любящей семьи.
Вот и устраивали различные обряды, чтоб показать этой злой силе, что ребёночек как-бы не свой, обмануть беду, обхитрить...
Например, клали в огород, а потом "случайно" находили и громко изумлялись по этому поводу.
Или - клали на обочине дороги, а "случайный" прохожий находил, и "искал" семью, куда бы пристроить найдёныша, и просил как бы случайно встреченных родителей взять малыша в свою семью, пригреть... И того, кто находил, часто просили стать крёстным отцом или матерью ребёночка.
И когда клали малыша на обочину, подстилали... отгадайте с трёх раз... конечно, капустные листья!

https://vk.com/wall-70531716_607

Answer (score 0):

Околоплодный пузырь с ребенком внутри отдаленно напоминает велок капусты.

Comment: да. Но вярд ли о том думают мамы сообщающие детям капустную версию возникновения рода человеческого.

Answer (score 0):

Цветная капуста в Японии считается символом плодородия, и по этому есть такая примета и до сих пор, делать свадебные букеты из цветной капусты. Тогда невеста будет плодородить в семье...может быть это и есть секрет населения Японии))))

Answer (score 0):

В Украинский культуре взрослые часто называли половые органы словами, похожими на них визуально: кукуруза, огурец, перец… и женский: капуста (разрезаний пополам кочан капусты напоминает внешне женские половые органы) и куница (раньше не брились).
Одна из версий в украинской культуре, что детей находят там, откуда они появляются - в «капусте»

Comment: Скажите, а с какой, простите, культуры вы слово "украинский" пишете с заглавной?